# Ubuntu says printing is completed even though my printer didn't print anything

Tags: printing, epson

I have an epson l120 printer and have installed it successfully. It prints test pages using epson utility app and nozzle checks are fine. When I try to print a pdf or document file my printer doesnt do anything but my laptop says that printing is done.

Comment: i have a similar problem printing pdf files but on a HP printer.printing the same files from libre office does not have this problem.ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.you might want to update your question with more details.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Is the program you used to print the test page an Ubuntu program?

Comment: im running 20.4. and printed test page using epson printer utility program

Answer (score 0):

Most of these problems are because your laptop does not have the corrent / no driver

I assume this is correct: `https://www.epson.com.ph/Support/Printers/Ink-Tank-Printers/L-Series/Epson-L120/s/SPT_C11CD76401?review-filter=Mac+OS+X+10.11.x`

Choose Linux (maybe [this link](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=SG&CTI=4&PRN=L120%20Series&OSC=LX) works)...
Download the latest deb file and once downloaded write: `sudo apt install ./downloads/*.deb # you might want to replace the *`

If already installed try to reconfigure the printer (remove it out of the list and add again, make sure it doesn't add automatically. You might have 2 printers then, just use this one you have set up byself)

Comment: this deb file is already installed.

Comment: make sure you enable this driver for the printer (or reconfigure the printer might help)

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a similar issue with an Epson printer. As a temporary fix, then printing a pdf from the GUI app did not work, but printing from the command line was ok:

```
lp nameof.pdf -d nameofprinter
```

find out the name of your printer like this

```
lpstat -p -d
```